# Use image inside list-group-item occupying all inner space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How I should stylize this:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media">
      <img th:if="${geral.logo}" th:src="@{/imagem/download/__${geral.logo.id}__}" width="180px" height="360px" class="mr-3" th:alt="${geral.titulo}">
      <svg th:unless="${geral.logo}" width="180px" height="360px" class="bd-placeholder-img mr-3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 64x64">
        <title>Placeholder</title>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" transform="rotate(90)" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em" th:text="${geral.titulo}"></text>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
...
</div>
```

In a way the image occupy all the space of the `list-group-item` element without blank spaces between the edges of the image and the border of the item.

**update**

I've tried this:

html:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <div class="media logo">
      <img th:if="${geral.logo}" th:src="@{/imagem/download/__${geral.logo.id}__}" width="180px" height="360px" class="mr-3" th:alt="${geral.titulo}">
      <svg th:unless="${geral.logo}" class="bd-placeholder-img mr-3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 64x64">
        <title>Placeholder</title>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" transform="rotate(90)" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em" th:text="${geral.titulo}"></text>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
...
</div>
```

css:

```
li.list-group-item {
  padding: 0;
}
.logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

but I keep seeing a empty space to the right of the image.

**update 2**

html:

```
<div class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" th:href="@{/}">
    <div class="media">
      <img th:if="${geral.logo}" th:src="@{/imagem/download/__${geral.logo.id}__}" width="180px" height="360px" th:alt="${geral.titulo}">
      <svg th:unless="${geral.logo}" class="bd-placeholder-img" width="180px" height="360px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 64x64">
        <title>Placeholder</title>
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em" th:text="${geral.titulo}"></text>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </li>
...
</div>
```

css:

```
.media img {
  padding: 0;
}
.bd-placeholder-img {
  padding: 0;
}
```

**final solution**

following the suggestion in the answer below, I use this css to accomplish what I wanted:

```
.list-group {
  margin-top: -128px;
  width: 180px;
}
li.list-group-item {
  padding: 0;
}
```

only managed to do that with the `padding: 0` added to `list-group-item` and `width: 180px` added to `list-group`.

Comment: I've tried the code added to the question (see update), but I keep seeing a empty space between the image and the border of the `list-group`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
.list-group-item{
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: this works fine for top, bottom and left padding, but not for the right. why?

Comment: class="mr-3" mean is margin-rigth:3px

Comment: ok, I remove this `class` (see update 2 for the current code I using), and know all the sides have a empty space between the image and the border of the `list-group`.

Comment: what do you want it to be

Comment: I want that the image occupy all space of the `list-group-item`, with no empty spaces between the image and the borders.

Comment: why you are not use this `.list-group-item{
        padding: 0;
    }`

Comment: I tried that, and keep getting a empty space in the right side only, even if I remove the `class="mr-3"`

Comment: use a reset css this may be the problem. https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/